# SQL search best match

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Entity(String market, Integer type, Integer z0, Integer z1, Integer z2, Integer z3, String mail)
```

These values except the `mail` field are nullable.

What I want to do is a request that retrieve an Entity and especially the mail field by all the other fields and use the `null` input as wildcard. **So retrieve the best match.**

For example imagine that I have this in database:

```
Entity("FR", null, null, null, null, null, "1@1.fr")
Entity("FR",    1,    1,    5, null, null, "2@2.fr")
Entity("FR",    2, null,    6,    7,    8, "3@3.fr")
Entity("FR",    2, null,    6,   12, null, "4@4.fr")
Entity("FR",    2, null, null,    7, null, "5@5.fr")
```

When I search with these values: `("FR", 2, 37, 6, 12, 58)` I should get the `"4@4.fr"` mail.

I already try a request like this but obviously it's not working, it will always return the first entity:

```
        "SELECT d FROM Entity d WHERE " +
        "(d.market = :market OR d.market = NULL)" +
        "AND (d.type= :typeOR d.type IS NULL)" +
        "AND (d.z0 = :z0 OR d.z0 IS NULL)" +
        "AND (d.z1 = :z1 OR d.z1 IS NULL)" +
        "AND (d.z2 = :z2 OR d.z2 IS NULL)" +
        "AND (d.z3 = :z3 OR d.z3 IS NULL) "
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the *best* match.  For that, you can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

That would be:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM Entity d
WHERE (d.market = :market OR d.market = NULL) AND
      (d.type = :typeOR d.type IS NULL) AND
      (d.z0 = :z0 OR d.z0 IS NULL) AND
      (d.z1 = :z1 OR d.z1 IS NULL) AND
      (d.z2 = :z2 OR d.z2 IS NULL) AND
      (d.z3 = :z3 OR d.z3 IS NULL)
ORDER BY ( (d.market = :market)::int + (d.type = :typeOR)::int +
           (d.z0 = :z0)::int + (d.z1 = :z1)::int +
           (d.z2 = :z2)::int + (d.z3 = :z3)::int
         ) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I try it with changing `::int` by `CAST((d.market = :market) AS INTEGER)` in order to make it work with my system, but when I use the request I still got the full null Entity in first

Comment: I also try in SQLDeveloper the raw query and same output, I have the wrong order :/

Comment: @Jessy . . . Your question is tagged Postgres, and `::int` is very much Postgres syntax.

Comment: Yeah but I have to use `CAST` as my request will be in JPQL to work with JPA & Spring boot, but even using `::int` with the plain SQL request in SQLDeveloper the sort is wrong

Comment: @Jessy . . . You can use a `case` expression instead (`case when d.market = :market then 1 else 0 end) + . . . `).  But as written, this works in Postgres which is how your question is tagged.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a predicate that will requires at least 1 of the null-able columns to be not null. You can get this converting each (except market) to a string and then the concat function, testing the result for not null. Adding to the answer by @GordonLinoff we arrive at:

```
select d.*
from entity d
where (d.market = :market or d.market is null)  
  and (d.type = :type or d.type is null)  
  and (d.z0 = :z0 or d.z0 is null)  
  and (d.z1 = :z1 or d.z1 is null)  
  and (d.z2 = :z2 or d.z2 is null)  
  and (d.z3 = :z3 or d.z3 is null)
  and (concat (d.market
              ,to_char(d.type)
              ,to_char(d.z0)
              ,to_char(d.z1)
              ,to_char(d.z2)
              ,to_char(d.z3)
              )
      ) is not null
order by ( (d.market = :market)::int + (d.type = :type)::int +
           (d.z0 = :z0)::int + (d.z1 = :z1)::int +
           (d.z2 = :z2)::int + (d.z3 = :z3)::int
         ) d.sc
limit 1;
```